# сортировка строки массива numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Требуется отсортировать только первую строку двумерного массива по возрастанию так, чтобы вторая строка была связана с первой.

Из массива:

```
a = ([[30,  10,  20],
      [ 0,   1,   2]])
```

на выходе нужно получить:

```
b = ([[10,  20,  30],
      [ 1,   2,   0]])
```

С помощью *np.argsort* сортируется каждая строка по возрастанию:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([30,20,10])
b = np.array([0, 1, 2])
a = np.vstack((a, b))
ind = np.argsort(a, axis = 1)
b = np.take_along_axis(a, ind, axis=1)
print(b)
```

Получается:

```
[[10 20 30]
 [ 0  1  2]]
```

Нужно, чтобы вторая строка не сортировалась, а была привязана к первой строке.

Comment: Тогда у вас не двумерный массив, а набор пар ключ:значение.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Из предложенных способов мой работает быстрее всего, поэтому выбирается как правильный.   Нужно найти индексы сортируемой строки и применить их при сортировке к обеим строкам:

```
import numpy as np
stroka_1 = np.array([30, 10, 20])
stroka_2 = np.array([0, 1, 2])
massiv = np.vstack((stroka_1, stroka_2))
print(massiv)
ind_1 = np.argsort(massiv[0])
stroka_1 = np.take_along_axis(massiv[0], ind_1, axis=0)
stroka_2 = np.take_along_axis(massiv[1], ind_1, axis=0)
massiv = np.vstack((stroka_1, stroka_2))
print(massiv)
```

Comment: в таком случае зачем вам вообще функционал numpy? это вы сейчас смастерили "феррари" на педальной тяге.

Comment: Почему ты решил, что _я_ поставил тебе "минус"?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[30,  10,  20], [ 0,   1,   2]])
```

исходный:

```
[[30 10 20]
 [ 0  1  2]]
```

Сортируем:

```
a = a[:, a[0].argsort()]
```

Получаем:

```
[[10 20 30]
 [ 1  2  0]]
```

Comment: Изящно, но медленнее, чем мой способ

Answer (score 0):

Сортировку можно сделать с помощью метода sort() и потом заменить 1ю не сортированную строка на сортированную:

```
import numpy as np
a = ([[30,  10,  20],
  [ 0,   1,   2]])
z = np.sort(a[0])
a[0] = z
print(a)
```

Результат такой как вам нужен.

Comment: MZaytsev, не такой

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение времени обработки двух способов решения поставленной задачи:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pylab
import statistics
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

dlina_strok = 10**7

y1 = []
y2 = []
x = []
vremya_1 = []
vremya_2 = []
n = 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):

    global n
    global x
    global y1
    global y2

    massiv_1 = np.random.sample((2, dlina_strok))
    massiv_2 = massiv_1.copy()

#==================== СПОСОБ № 1 ============================
    t1 = time.time()
    a = massiv_1[:, massiv_1[0].argsort()]
    t1 = time.time() - t1
#============================================================
    vremya_1.append(t1)
    y1.append(statistics.mean(vremya_1))

    n = n + 1
    x.append(n)
    a = ax1.plot(x, y1, color = 'red', label='a = massiv_1[:, massiv_1[0].argsort()]')

#==================== СПОСОБ № 2 ============================
    t2 = time.time()
    ind_1 = np.argsort(massiv_2[0])
    stroka_1 = np.take_along_axis(massiv_2[0], ind_1, axis=0)
    stroka_2 = np.take_along_axis(massiv_2[1], ind_1, axis=0)
    b = np.vstack((stroka_1, stroka_2))
    t2 = time.time() - t2
#============================================================
    vremya_2.append(t2)
    y2.append(statistics.mean(vremya_2))
    a = ax1.plot(x, y2, color = 'green', label='Способ № 2')

    a = ax1.set_ylabel('Время обработки, с')
    a = ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)
    a = ax1.set_ylim(0, 1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1)
a = plt.show()
```